# Why is it impossible to create this directory?

Tags: php, linux

I want to create a directory in a Linux system. The parent directory which will contain the newly created directory has a 777 permission. The problem is that if the new directory doesn't include a subdirectory then it is created successfully. But when it contains a subdirectory , for example `docs/photos` then the subdirectory ( here /photos ) is not created ! So how to make the subdirectory created ?

Here is the codes :

```
    if (!file_exists($rep))
    {
        if (mkdir($rep))
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_field']['tmp_name'] , $rep."/"."photo".$image_id.".png");
        }
    }
```

Comment: conform me if you hava a string like doc/abc/xyz then we need to create doc directory inside that abc inside abc we have to create xyz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) indicates that there is a `$recursive` parameter you should use for this.

> `recursive`
>
> Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname. Defaults to FALSE.

Read the docs for usage.

Comment: Does the `file_exists` function looks at the subdirectory ?

Comment: That question doesn't make sense. If the path doesn't exist, the file can't exist. If the file exists, then all the components of its path do exist.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `mkdir` does not recursively create subdirectories. If you want such a behavior, you have to add the `recursive` parameter: `mkdir($rep, 0777, true)`.See the [doc](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.mkdir.php) for more details.

(By the way, you should avoid 777 permissions, they *very often* cause security issues.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a third parameter, you have to set to TRUE to make it work. This parameter is for recursive. Otherwise PHP will only create the "root" dir

http://de.php.net/mkdir